How to calculate the z-score with replicates?
I have data from an essay. The assay was performed for 6 different cell culture conditions (columns) and for 6 genes (rows). However, it was also performed 5 times per each gene (for statistical purposes).
An example of our data:



Genes
Condition 1
Condition 2




Gene 1 replicate 1
0.22
120


Gene 1 replicate 2
0.34
122


Gene 1 replicate 3
0.45
119


Gene 1 replicate 4
0.33
34


Gene1 replicate 5
0.55
90


Gene 2 replicate 1
12
0.1


Gene 2 replicate 2
19.3
0.45


Gene 2 replicate 3
23.4
NA


Gene 2 replicate 4
11.7
0.89


Gene 2 replicate 5
12.4
0.1



And so on...for 6 genes and 6 conditions. Unfortunately we also have 2 NA values, which doesn't mean they are 0, it's just that they are undetectable by the machine (below detectable value).
Now. With these data I have to make a heatmap and for that I need z-scores. While I know how to calculate z-scores, I am not sure what to do when there are multiple replicates. Do you do the mean? In another case I saw something with Pearson (?).
In the end the idea is to get 1 z-score for each gene and each condition, so that I can make a heatmap. Moreover, there is an outlier (replicate 4), so it would probably be more meaningful to use the median rather than the mean.
The final heatmap will represent the changes of these genes expression in the different conditions. Basically in the end we want to compare the conditions based on their gene expressions, and state "this cell culture condition has this gene pattern, which is different from that cell culture condition"
I tried a couple of codes to calculate the z-scores, but I'm not sure they are correct.
It was difficult for me to tell R what mean (or median) to use to calculate z-scores, since there are replicates, and then to pull the values together.

Interesting question, but it is off topic here since it is mostly conceptual. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

You could make an array out of your data,
> n_genes <- 2; n_reps <- 5; n_cond <- 2
> A <- array(unlist(dat[-1]), 
+            dim=c(n_reps, n_cond, n_genes),
+            dimnames=list(NULL,
+                          unique(sub('\\srepli.*', '', dat$Genes)), 
+                          names(dat)[-1])) |>
+   aperm(c(1, 3, 2))
> A
, , Gene 1

     Condition.1 Condition.2
[1,]        0.22         120
[2,]        0.34         122
[3,]        0.45         119
[4,]        0.33          34
[5,]        0.55          90

, , Gene 2

     Condition.1 Condition.2
[1,]        12.0        0.10
[2,]        19.3        0.45
[3,]        23.4          NA
[4,]        11.7        0.89
[5,]        12.4        0.10

calculate z-scores from mean values (Since outliers are removed, there's no need to consider the median. This might introduce some bias; to learn about how to address this bias, you could ask on Cross Validated.),
> ## z-scores from gene-means
> z <- \(x) {(x - mean(x))/sd(x)}
> (m <- colMeans(A, na.rm=TRUE) |> t() |> z())
       Condition.1 Condition.2
Gene 1  -0.6045887   1.4815124
Gene 2  -0.2724862  -0.6044375

and plot a heatmap.
> ## heatmap
> png('foo.png')
> m |> heatmap(margins=c(17, 12))
> dev.off()


Edit
An easier approach, in particular if no imputation or similar interim steps are needed, might be to directly calculate m using colMeans in by
> m <- by(dat[-1], sub('\\srepli.*', '', dat$Genes), colMeans, na.rm=TRUE) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> 
+   z() 
> m
       Condition.1 Condition.2
Gene 1  -0.6045887   1.4815124
Gene 2  -0.2724862  -0.6044375


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Genes = c("Gene 1 replicate 1", "Gene 1 replicate 2", 
"Gene 1 replicate 3", "Gene 1 replicate 4", "Gene 1 replicate 5", 
"Gene 2 replicate 1", "Gene 2 replicate 2", "Gene 2 replicate 3", 
"Gene 2 replicate 4", "Gene 2 replicate 5"), Condition.1 = c(0.22, 
0.34, 0.45, 0.33, 0.55, 12, 19.3, 23.4, 11.7, 12.4), Condition.2 = c(120, 
122, 119, 34, 90, 0.1, 0.45, NA, 0.89, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


Why do you impute with the median, when we know the NAs are due to the values being below the detectability threshold?

Because the OP requested it, @AkselA. Statistics may be discussed on Cross Validated.

I agree, but we can still try to avoid giving bad statistical advice. I can't see where the OP requested to have the NAs imputed with the median?

@AkselA "Moreover, there is an outlier (replicate 4), so it would probably be more meaningful to use the median rather than the mean." Feel free to add your statistical advice, we might move the Q to CV then, though.

It's more a matter of understanding what the OP is asking for. The outlier isn't encoded as as NA, and they don't want it 'dealt with', but rather wondering whether a more robust measure of location would be appropriate.

@AkselA You're right, I might have misread, that the NA is due to deleted outlyer and should just be removed, They mean calculate the average with na.omit. But since it's removed, mean should be sufficient, Can you confirm?

Yes, at this stage that should suffice. It will impart a positive bias, and z-score assumptions might not hold, but that discussion is best had on CV.

@AkselA Good, I've edited my answer accordingly.

@jay.sf  thank you very much for the interesting discussion. I had to update my question because I noticed a mistake. We did 5 replicates per each gene and not 4, but the problem itself doesn't change. In the end from our analysis we got 180 values, only 2 of which are NA (both in gene 5 replicate 2). I confirm that for the whole analysis replicate 4 has behaved as an outlier, but doesn't have any NA values.

@Marta The workflow won't change, except defining second dimension of the array. (Just noted that I forgot the line where the n_* are defined.)

@Marta Please note alternative solution I've added in an edit. Let me know if it worked for you.
